# Exception ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0>=0 while retrieving a value from JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, indexoutofboundsexception

i'm writing here because i have searched everywhere but didn't find any solution to solve my problem.
My app uses a .txt file to store Title, Genre, Main Characters and Status of a DVD list and a JTable to show the list.
I want to delete a DVD from the list by selecting the row in the JTable and press "Elimina" button. 
I'm getting this Exception while trying to retrieve the title of selected row:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0 >= 0
at java.base/java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:463)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel.getValueAt(DefaultTableModel.java:660)
at my.dvdmanager.DvdList_frame.btnYesActionPerformed(DvdList_frame.java:335)
at my.dvdmanager.DvdList_frame$1.actionPerformed(DvdList_frame.java:111)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1967)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2308)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:405)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:262)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:279)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6636)
at java.desktop/javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3342)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6401)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2263)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:5012)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2321)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4918)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4547)
at java.desktop/java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4488)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2307)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2762)
at java.desktop/java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4844)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:772)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:721)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:715)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:95)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:745)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$5.run(EventQueue.java:743)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:391)
at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:85)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:742)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:203)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:124)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:113)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:109)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:90)
```

And this is the piece of code where there is the problem:

```
DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) dvdList_table.getModel();
    //get selected row index
    int selectedRowInd = 0;
    try {
        //removes selected row
        selectedRowInd = dvdList_table.convertRowIndexToModel(dvdList_table.getSelectedRow());
        System.out.println("selectedRowInd:" + selectedRowInd);
        model.removeRow(selectedRowInd);

    } catch(Exception e) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }

    String path = "dvdlist.txt", dvdToErase = (String) dvdList_table.getModel().getValueAt(selectedRowInd, 0); //Exception raises up here
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: (1) Note that if there is no selected row, `getSelectedRow` will return -1. Best have a check for that. (2) You are reusing the row model index you removed from the model in the last line. If you had one row before removing the line, you have none afterwards. Don't reuse that same row model index.

Comment: (1) I'll do it thanks. (2) Should i retrieve the title first and then remove the row?

Answer (score 0):

I have found my mistake (thanks @TT), i had to retrieve the title first and then delete the row